# QGIS MMQGIS geocode behind proxy

Tags: geocoding, python-2.7, proxy

I have been having trouble with MMQGIS geocoding that I am using behind proxy. Yes I had set the proxy settings from Settings>Options>Network correctly and was able to get connected to the internet but MMQGIS still didn't work and threw error upon running geocode. I could not find any useful help for this issue anywhere online, after weeks I realized the program works on another machine that had QGIS installed recently, this make me think there could be something about the version of QGIS, so I upgraded my QGIS to 2.14, but still the error persisted. Then it dawned to me to uninstall and reinstall MMQGIS plugin (yes even after uninstalling QGIS, the machine had preserved my older installation plugins). So I installed the recent version of MMQGIS and there we go, it worked. The issue seems to be the certain version of MMQGIS that I was using. I am copying the full error here in case this helps others, it wasted hours of my time.

Full error log with personal info masked:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py",
>   line 1198, in run
>       shapefilename, notfoundfile, fields, service, 1)   File "C:/Users/USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py",
>   line 1890, in mmqgis_geocode_web_service
>       x, y, addrtype, addrlocat, formatted_addr = mmqgis_geocode_address_google(address)   File
>   "C:/Users/USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py",
>   line 175, in mmqgis_geocode_address_google
>       xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()   File "~QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
>       h.endheaders(data)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 791, in send
>       self.connect()   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 772, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "~\QGISsrc\apps\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in
>   create_connection
>       raise err IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond